# How to extract address into cells from excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2013, microsoft-excel-2016

I have addresses in one cell and I want to extract them in different cells on the same row. Some cells have four lines of address and some have three. I am able to easily split using text to column and various delimiters for the ones with three but not the ones with four.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yHkvd.png)

In the first example I have four lines and second has three

```
Anchorage Oncology Centre
3801 University Lake Drive
Suite 300-B2
Anchorage, AK 99508 US
```

I would like the above as split into 5 cells. One cell each for address, City, State, Zip code and country

```
Anchorage Oncology Centre
3801 University Lake Drive
Suite 300-B2


Anchorage

AK 

99508 

US
```

in second example below

```
Providence Alaska Medical Center
3200 Providence Drive
Anchorage, AK 99508 US
```

I would like

```
Providence Alaska Medical Center
3200 Providence Drive

Anchorage

AK 

99508 

US
```

Could this be done using a formula?

Thank you

Comment: *Could this be done using a formula?* Yes, it is possible, but the formula will be too complex. I recommend UDF.

Answer (score 0):

assuming the "Anchorage, AK 99508 US" text is located at A1, enter these formulas..

```
A4 --> =MID(A1,1,(FIND(",",A1,1))-1)
B4 --> =MID($A$1,(FIND(" ",$A$1,A3))+1,C3-(FIND(" ",$A$1,A3))-1)
C4 --> =MID($A$1,(FIND(" ",$A$1,(FIND(" ",$A$1,FIND(",",A1,1)))+1))+1,(FIND(" ",$A$1,(FIND(" ",$A$1,(FIND(" ",$A$1,FIND(",",A1,1)))+1))+1))-(FIND(" ",$A$1,(FIND(" ",$A$1,FIND(",",A1,1)))+1))-1)
D4 --> =MID($A$1,(FIND(" ",$A$1,(FIND(" ",$A$1,(FIND(" ",$A$1,FIND(",",A1,1)))+1))+1))+1,LEN(A1))
```

key : find() was used to identify the start/end value for mid(). here we find 
each "," & " " in the A1 text.

Answer (score 0):

Or... you could take a rather different approach. Two, in fact.

One is to use the `FILTERXML()` technique. One goes to the work of splitting your data into two pieces, the "rest of it" and the last line. The "rest of it" goes into the first output cell. (I'll show below a fairly easy way to divide the pieces.) The last line is worked on as a string to replace the comma-space and spaces with HTML tags (`</Something><Something>`) half-transforming the string into an HTML string, then have the opening tag prepended and the closing tag appended, further adding the outer HTML tags wrapping all that. This is the actual input to the `FILTERXML()` function and its output is the four cells holding the last line's info.

That is easier than it sounds, and becomes cookie-cutter after a few times used, if close in time. The main effort is dividing the data into pieces and prepping them. That's because each new use seems to have data packaged differently.

One advantage, besides the cookie-cutter nature after practice, is it produces an array output "naturally" rather than needing `{CSE}` entry (<kbd>Ctrl-Shift-Enter</kbd>). Another is that you can select the output elements by number, or with `[Last]` (and this element of the addressing can be built with string techniques) so you can extract exact positional data if you can specify it.

A different approach is to use an `Excel 4 Macro` ("E4M") command called `EVALUATE()`. You cannot use it directly in a cell formula, but must create a Named Range to hold it. You can create what you present to it in cells or work it all out into a single formula and place that inside the function in the Named Range. Whatever works best for you or suits your proclivities best.

In any case, like with `FILTERXML()`, you must prepare the input. The difference here is that the things you do this way are very familiar and little things that go wrong, leaving out a comma or making a typo, look "natural" and are relatively easy to find. With `FILTERXML()` everything looks "wrong" and you will, for a time, have no familiarity with what the output should look like so errors are easier to make and harder to find. Advantage, `EVALUATE()`.

So, how to prepare the data? You need two chunks:  the first part (that I called the "rest of it" above) that you will just extract and present, and the part you want worked in the special way. Then in the last part, you will create a string that looks like the kind of array Excel produces internally in its formulas. One that would display across a row might look like `{"a","b",1,"K"}` and the same data created to display down a column would look like `{"a";"b";1;"K"}` and of course, they can be mixed to display over a range of columns and rows. You wish to create one like the latter, with the semi-colons for delimiters.

But you don't have a single delimiter in the last line. You have ", " and " ". So first, you take that piece and put it into `SUBSTITUTE()` to change the ", " ("comma-space") into just the space. Now you have one delimiter only and can change it, with `SUBSTITUTE()`, to the ";" that you need. You can also apply most of the doublequotes you need around all the elements by using `";"` instead of just the `;`. In actual fact, since Excel makes using the doublequotes as formula elements rather obnoxious, using `CHAR(34)` for them is much easier. "Most of the" because you can only add them in between elements with `SUBSTIITUTE()` leaving the beginning and ending doublequotes still needed. So you add them in the opening and ending strings along with the appropriate of the curly braces. You now have a suitable string, one that `EVALUATE()` can tear apart.

Build that in a cell and once it works, create the Named Range and put it all inside `EVALUATE()`'s parentheses. You'll see in the formula below how that looks. It is not clear how your output will sit, relative to the input data, so I've just used the two rows beneath one input, so input in A1, output in A2 and A3. You can adjust as desired. So, inside the Named Range:

```
=EVALUATE("{"&CHAR(34)&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-MAX(IFERROR(FIND(CHAR(10),A1,SEQUENCE(1,LEN(A1))),""))),", "," ")," ",CHAR(34)&";"&CHAR(34))&CHAR(34)&"}")
```

`SEQUENCE()` might've been available when the question was written. Might not've. I used it for simplicity since, after all, I AM writing for folks searching on the problem but wanting an up to date solution. However, substitutes for it existed then, the common one using `ROW(1:xxx)` either simply or in complex ways.

"In the day", it might have needed entered with `{CSE}` entry.

It does all the things already talked about.

The small element here is how to divide apart the input. Every problem differs, but your is not too, too hard. Each line in the input cell ends with <kbd>Alt-Enter</kbd>, or `CHAR(10)`. So you can count them using the "length the content minus the length of the content after `SUBSTITUTE()` removes them" technique. Then you wrap around that a `FIND()` that does something not usually done:  it uses the "position number" parameter (third one) to take an array of values from 1 to the length of the input so you have an array of `FIND()`'s each looking one place further into the input. That yields an array of values of the next occurrence as it goes through the input with errors at the end since there is stuff after the last one. Can't use those errors, so `IFERROR()` blanks them out. The highest number found is the breaking point for the input, so use `MAX()` to output that. Then you do two formulas, a `LEFT()` of that many characters to get all the easy, just dump in place first few lines (however many, 3,4,5,whatever, that it might be). Then a `RIGHT()` of the input of the length of the input minus this breaking point collects the rest. That is the input for the `EVALUATE()` function.

Like with `FILTERXML()`, that is all actually pretty easy since the massaging of the material has to be done whichever way you go. Then it just plunks into `EVALUATE()`.